# how cancellation token stop continue with?

Tags: c#, winforms, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I have a Thread with this code:

```
foreach (string file in allDirectoriesFiles)
{
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        return;
    }

    // ... some operation...
}

// ... some operation 2...
```

notice that I use `return` instead of `break`, because if I stop the thread the `some operation 2` must not be executed.

I also notice that in this manner the .ContinueWith it is not executed.

Well, but that is just a "return" function. How can C# know that I'm returning due to the `tokenSource.Cancel()` instead of a usual return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create the continuation with the same cancellation token or else the continuation will also be cancelled, even before it is executed. Create the continuation with a different cancellation token (from a different cancellation source) or simply create it without a cancellation token if you always want the cancellation to execute.

Comment: Well! So: if current thread is executed, I can only stop it checking the cancellation token inside of it (it in fact won't force the exit of the thread. In other words: It will continue till the end if I don't check that token. Instead, if the continue function is not started, it won't if cancellation token is called (without I check manually). Right?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Even 'normal' tasks do not get executed if the cancellation token (with which it was created) was cancelled before the task is processed by the task scheduler. You only check the token in your own task so that you can cancel a long running loop, etc. O, and just a note: ending a task does not necessarily mean the thread (on which ot runs) exits, even if an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

A [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx) is meant to propagate the cancelling to the whole set of actions at once. Once you [Cancel()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955.aspx) its source, the other continuations won't be called.